# Is It Possible for this Script to be Generalised?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I'm very new to jQuery with little programming experience so please take that into consideration.

I created a timesaving script that will take the following two variables:

1) An element (which contains a single image) - `imgelement`

2) An image URL for the hover image - `hoverimageurl`

**Code:**

```js
/* Image Hover Script (Start) */
    var imgelement = "#element"; /* Element containing the original image */
    var hoverimageurl = "http://www.domain.com/image.png2"; /* Image URL of the hover image */
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
     /* Add CSS and a class to the original image to fix positioning and give it an identification */
     jQuery(imgelement + " img").addClass("originalimage");
      
     /* Prepend hover image to the element. Set the SRC to the hover image URL */
     jQuery(imgelement).prepend('<img class="hoverimage" src="' + hoverimageurl + '">');
     
     /* Fade out original image and fade in hover image on hover */
     jQuery(imgelement).hover(function() {
      jQuery(imgelement + " .originalimage").stop(true).fadeTo(1000, 0);
      jQuery(imgelement + " .hoverimage").stop(true).fadeTo(1000, 1);
     }, function() {
      jQuery(imgelement + " .hoverimage").stop(true).fadeTo(1000, 0);
      jQuery(imgelement + " .originalimage").stop(true).fadeTo(1000, 1);
     });
     
    });
    /* Image Hover Script (End) */
```

```css
/* Image Hover CSS (Start) */
#pix-fe .originalimage {
 position: relative;
}

#pix-fe .hoverimage {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
/* Image Hover CSS (End) */
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <a href="http://www.domain.com"><img src="http://www.domain.com/image1.png"></a>
</div>
```

What the script does is fade to the hover image given from the `hoverimageurl` variable when the element is hovered. This works perfectly but I will want to use multiple instances of this script and to do so I would need to append the variable names with an incrementing number for each instance that I require. This is inefficient because the bulk of the script will need to be repeated per instance when ideally I would just like a variable list and one instance of the main script.

Is there any way at all that I can achieve generalisation of this code? I am aware of `this` but `imgelement` will always refer to the value against the `imgelement` variable specifically so with my knowledge I cannot see how this can be done.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I'm sure you can DRY this up, but we would need to also see your HTML. Could you please edit your question to include it.

Comment: What would happen if you tried to make the selector fit more tightly? E.g my targeting it to `#element :hover`? Shouldn't `this` reference a single instance in that case?

Comment: @seth The selector is already wrong; an ID should be unique. A class would be better and I'm guessing `$('.example').each(function(){console.log(this)})` would have the best results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, my mistake. Still your solution would need an extension to make it `$('.example :hover') ...` if I'm not mistaken as the script is only supposed to trigger on the element that is being hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really do something like this using css as it will be more reliable than js and easier to understand. That said this is a good opportunity to learn about jQuery plugins and how you can utilize it to make your code more DRY and reusable.

To add a new method to the jQuery object you can declare a function on `jQuery.fn` which is it's `prototype`.

in your function `this` will be bound to the collection of elements that you have selected, so you need to call each over it if you are planning on making the api work on collections.

From there you simply need to add your functionality to the function. Any arguments will be passed into your function so you can pass in settings at runtime. here it is used to pass in the img url.

The other basic function I used was `jQuery.fn.find` as we have the reference element that we can traverse the dom from, rather than using strings which are more confusing to my eyes.

To run the plugin you simply need to make a jQuery selector and call your new method. `$('#selector').hoverImage('url')`

Now that you know the basics of creating a jQuery plugin, you should really figure out how to achieve the same outcome with pure css.

```js
/*
 * jQuery hoverImage plugin
 *
 * @param {string}  url  url of the hover image
*/
(function() {
  jQuery.fn.hoverImage = function(url) {
    // loop over the element collection
    this.each(function() {
      // bind your functionality
      var $this = $(this)
      var $img = $this.find('img')
      var $hover = $('<img class="hoverimage" src="' + url + '">')
      
      $this.prepend($hover)
      
      $this.hover(function() {
        $img.stop().fadeTo(1000,0)
        $hover.stop().fadeTo(1000,1)
      }, function() {
        $img.stop().fadeTo(1000,1)
        $hover.stop().fadeTo(1000,0)
      })
    })
  }
})()
// run your plugin
$('#element').hoverImage('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing that little css can't handle :)

```css
.image-switch {
  position: relative;
}

.image-switch img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s
}

.image-switch:hover img:last-child{
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<span class="image-switch">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/FF0000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you Endless.